# ubuntu 18.04 java installation problem

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, java

Everytime I try to install java on Ubuntu 18.04 (on a VirtualBox VM) with the following command (I've tried several other commands/methods from other topics/forums):

```
sudo apt install default-jdk
```

No matter what I do, when the time comes to retrieve headers, I get the following error:

```
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Err:2 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
 Connection failed [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
Err:3 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
 Connection failed [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
Err:4 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
 Connection failed [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease
 Connection failed [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease
 Connection failed [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease
 Connection failed [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that isn't possible to connect to these repositories, or they are not available anymore.

Sorry, but, just to check. Do you have access to the Internet in this VirtualBox OS? Then, look up how to change the repository source for Ubuntu 18.04.

I didn't answer precisely because I haven't used Ubuntu in a long time, but I found this:

¹https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Adding%20Canonical%20Partner%20Repositories

²http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2018/03/how-to-change-ubuntu-repository-mirror-sources.html

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I do have internet access, and I'll look into changing the repository. I did, however, try a different source and got the same error so maybe I got unlucky twice?

Comment: @MiladDakka, do you saw "Enabling Canonical Partner Repositories" on the first link? Because I found on my search this statement: 'Since Ubuntu 10.4 the sun-java* packages have moved from the "Multiverse Repository" to the "Partner Repositories"'. Maybe you need adjust this specific setting, not the main repositories.